# How to set iframe correctly in web page

Tags: html, css

Here I give an code. I want to set the iframe but is not showing anything. I don't understand what is the problem.

```
<iframe src="https://twitter.com/money2020"></iframe>
```

Comment: yes I have. Please see this  <iframe src="https://twitter.com/money2020" class="frame"></iframe>

Comment: I copy paste you code <iframe src="https://twitter.com/money2020"></iframe>. It is also not working.

Comment: Then what should I do ?

Comment: Press F12 and see that twitter does not like to be framed: _Refused to display 'https://twitter.com/money2020' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"._ Instead go here: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

Comment: I want to embade the link https://twitter.com/money2020 as iframe. How to do it. Please suggest.

Comment: We did. Visit the documentation page

Answer (score 0):

"Twitter's site blocks direct iframe display through the secure hypertext transfer protocol, which keeps someone from making a direct iframe to any given page on Twitter. Instead, Twitter widgets need to be created through the corresponding Twitter account to be embedded on a site within an iframe."

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Twitter-Hashtag-Widget

https://twitter.com/settings/widgets